# Edit files on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm stuck at this simple task.

I have some configuration files that should be ignored by Git. But after commit to Heroku, I always get **Application Error**.

If I ignore those files then I have no way to get around the situation, but adding them to Git is definitely not a good idea.

Is there any way to ssh into Heroku server, I found no instructions on Heroku?

Comment: if you want to ignore some file in the beginning by adding to `gitignore` can help otherwise you have to manually remove them by yourself and then adding the file name to giiignore can prevent further unwanted files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a bash shell for your heroku app by doing this.  Note that it will spin up another dyno, which will shut down when you exit the shell:

```
heroku run bash
```